# ASP.NET MVC JQuery UI TAB - How to make post-back on each tab click. How to make it SEO friendy?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, tabs, seo, postback

I am using jquery tab as given bellow. Clicking on each tab it make a AJAX call according to its href url. Problem is AJAX call is not SEO friendly. How i can make it SEO friendly? How to do a postback on each tab click and keep current tab as selected after postback. Also how to update url on each tab click i mean if user click on [SPECIFICATION] tab, after post back url should look like www.domnainname/cardetails/specification

I AM USING ASP.NET MVC 4.0.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ($) {
        $('#example').tabs();
    });
</script>


<div id="example"  class="tabs"  style="width: 698px;">
                <ul style="list-style: none;">
                    <li><a href="/Details/Overview" title="tabs-1">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Version/Details?ID=@ViewBag.versionId&grpId=5" title="tabs-2">Specifications</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Version/Details?ID=@ViewBag.versionId&grpId=1" title="tabs-3">Exterior</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Version/Details?ID=@ViewBag.versionId&grpId=2" title="tabs-4" >Interior</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Version/Details?ID=@ViewBag.versionId&grpId=3" title="tabs-5">Dimensions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Version/Details?ID=@ViewBag.versionId&grpId=4" title="tabs-6">Feature</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Version/Details?versionID=@ViewBag.versionId&grpId=6" title="tabs-7">Instrument Panel</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1" style="width: 698px;">
                    This is Tab one
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2">
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-3">
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-4">
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-5">
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-6">
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-7">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks,

@Paul

Comment: Are you loading content into the tab divs, or are you using the tabs as a sort of navigation?

Comment: I am loading content in to tabs. Each tab click load page into tab as per its href.

Comment: I've posted an answer for below, with a fiddle example.  Hope this is what you were looking for.  If it was, please remember to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are trying to do I would suggest the following:

- Replace href="/Your/links/address" with href="#corresponding-panel"
- Add a 'data-link' attribute to house your url
- Subscribe to tab's select event

  $(".tabs").tabs({select:function(ui, event){

  ```
  if(!$(event.panel).hasClass('loaded')){
      var linkURL = $(ui.currentTarget).attr('data-link');
      //Ajax load has happend
      if(linkURL != undefined){
          //USE the 'linkURL' variable in place of '/echo/json'
          $.ajax({
              url: "/echo/json" ,
              success:function(data){
                  $(event.panel).addClass('loaded').html("<h1>Some ajax content loaded from " + $(ui.currentTarget).attr('data-link') );
              }            
          });
      }
  } }});​
  ```

[Here is the JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/yKyu2/1/)

Comment: @Paul That depends on how SEO friendly you want to code the routes, controllers, actions, and params.